# Kafka CLI: command to list all consumer groups for a topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-producer-api

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group webapi-group
```

The above command gives me :

```
Error: Consumer group 'web-api' does not exist.
```

And rightly so because web-api group does not exist. I do not seem to remember what all consumer groups I had created. How do I see it?

I also tried:

```
bin\kafka-consumer-groups.sh -bootstrap-server localhost:9092 -list
```

But nothing happened.

**Edit:**
Upon firing :

```
bin\kafka-consumer-groups.sh -bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
```

A terminal window opened up for a few seconds and close on its own without any output.

[image]

Comment: Listing all groups "for a topic" doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --all-groups count_errors --describe
```

Use this command to list all groups and topic details. on having a consumer group you should be able to see similar response

```
Consumer group 'order-consumer-group' has no active members.

GROUP                TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
order-consumer-group checkins        0          18              25    

      7               -               -               -
```

Answer (score 0):

The earlier answer to this question didn't work for me, because my company has too many Kafka groups to list with a single command for all groups without timing out. I just got stack traces like the following when I ran the recommended command:

```
Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listOffsets(api=METADATA), deadlineMs=1698212646571, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1698212646676) timed out at 1698212646576 after 1 attempt(s)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listOffsets(api=METADATA), deadlineMs=1698212646571, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1698212646676) timed out at 1698212646576 after 1 attempt(s)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:396)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.getLogEndOffsets(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:638)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.$anonfun$collectGroupsOffsets$7(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:411)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:79)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.$anonfun$collectGroupsOffsets$2(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:567)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:584)
    at scala.collection.mutable.Growable.addAll(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.Growable.addAll$(Growable.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.addAll(HashMap.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$.from(HashMap.scala:604)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$.from(HashMap.scala:597)
    at scala.collection.MapOps$WithFilter.map(Map.scala:381)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.collectGroupsOffsets(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:560)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.describeGroups(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:367)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.run(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:72)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:59)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listOffsets(api=METADATA), deadlineMs=1698212646571, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1698212646676) timed out at 1698212646576 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: Cancelled listOffsets(api=METADATA) request with correlation id 10169 due to node 4 being disconnected
```

That being said, I came up with a decent workaround by piping commands that worked on my ZSH terminal on my Macbook:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <my-kafka-cluster>:9093 --command-config <my-cfg-file-name> --list \
| xargs -I% kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <my-kafka-cluster>:9093 --command-config <my-cfg-file-name> --group % --describe 2>/dev/null \
| grep -E <my-topic-name> \
| sed -E 's/^([^ ]+).*$/\1/' \
| sort | uniq
```

This script essentially generates a unique and sorted listing of all consumer groups and relies on the output from `kafka-consumer-groups` to be in the following format:

```
GROUP    TOPIC    PARTITION    CURRENT-OFFSET    LOG-END-OFFSET   
 LAG    CONSUMER-ID    HOST    CLIENT-ID
```

Basically, I'm listing all consumer groups on the first line.

On the second line, I'm describing each consumer group via the `xargs` command because I can't pipe the consumer group name directly into the `kafka-consumer-groups` command as a shell input. Note that I'm ignoring irrelevant error output lines such as `Consumer group '<some-group>' has no active members` via the `2>/dev/null` appendage. As part of the output, the topic name should be listed in the second column, in addition to the consumer group name in the first column.

Lastly, I filter out all lines that don't contain my desired topic name via `grep` on the third line. All columns of data except the consumer group ID (i.e. the first column) are truncated via the `sed` command, leaving only a list of consumer group IDs (likely containing duplicates because of partitions) that is unsorted. Finally, the list is sorted with all of duplicate elements removed via the `sort` and `uniq` commands.

Hopefully this helps somebody else in a similar situation.