# What is the consumer group used to consume from a kafka changelog topic?

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, prometheus, apache-kafka-streams

I have this `kafka-streams` application which is returning `Prometheus` metrics. If I were to believe these metrics, the application has a lag on most partitions of the changelog topic.

I wanted to verify these metrics using `kafka-cli`. I first thought the `application.id` would be the consumer group for the changelog topic, but with `kafka-consumer-groups --describe` command, I get information about input topics only.

So I have two question:

- What is the consumer group used to consume records from the changelog topic in `kafka-streams` ?
- How can I get the lag for each changelog partition using `kafka-cli` (or other method other than `Prometheus` metrics) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kafka CLI: command to list all consumer groups for a topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883999/kafka-cli-command-to-list-all-consumer-groups-for-a-topic)

Comment: @GaëlJ unfortunately not

Comment: What does the command returns when you list all consumer groups of the topic?

Comment: it returns all the consumer groups in the cluster with their input topics and lag. But nothing regarding the changelog topics.